# parsing in GO xml that has elements with arbitrary endings

Tags: xml, go

I try to parse xml file that has elements with arbitrary endings

Example of xml with Array0 and Array1:

```
<GetPriceChangesForReseller>
          <PriceContractArray0 actualtype="PriceContract">
            <EndUserPrice>1990,00</EndUserPrice>     
          </PriceContractArray0>
          <PriceContractArray1 actualtype="PriceContract">        
            <EndUserPrice>2290,00</EndUserPrice>
          </PriceContractArray1>  
</GetPriceChangesForReseller>
```

How can I work with this case?

a part of my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)


type GetPriceChangesForReseller struct {
    XMLName                    xml.Name             `xml:"GetPriceChangesForReseller"`
    GetPriceChangesForReseller []PriceContractArray `xml:"PriceContractArray"`
}


type PriceContractArray struct {
    XMLName             xml.Name `xml:"PriceContractArray"`
    Price               string   `xml:"Price"`
func main() {

// Open our xmlFile
xmlFile, err := os.Open("GetPriceChangesForReseller.xml")
// if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following structure ([try it online!](https://play.golang.org/p/GbgA9N1wx34)):

```
type GetPriceChangesForReseller struct {
    XMLName xml.Name        `xml:"GetPriceChangesForReseller"`
    Items   []PriceContract `xml:",any"`
}

type PriceContract struct {
    Price string `xml:"EndUserPrice"`
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [xmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/xmlquery), its easy to parse and query for XML document , without defined types like structs.

```golang
doc, err := xmlquery.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, n := range xmlquery.Find(doc, "//GetPriceChangesForReseller/*") {
        fmt.Printf("%s price: %s\n", n.Data, n.SelectElement("EndUserPrice").InnerText())
    }
```

> PriceContractArray0 price: 1990,00
>
> PriceContractArray1 price: 2290,00